# CORS policy error with AWS API Gateway in React

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, fetch-api, lambda-authorizer

I am trying to set up an API Gateway to call another lambda function that will upload an image to S3. The feature works well when I am using an app like POSTMAN, however when I run the browser using React I am getting the following error.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://.../upload' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

In my API Gateway I have the following configuration for that method

```
Gateway Responses for UserUpload API: default 4XX (not checked), default 5XX (not checked)
Methods: post (checked), options (checked)
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: options, post
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '*'
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
```

This API uses an authorizer, I am using the [one provided by Auth0](https://github.com/auth0-samples/jwt-rsa-aws-custom-authorizer) and have not edited the code at all.

And the function that my authorizer calls returns the response like the below (eg happy path):

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  //do data checks and upload to s3
  return {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: "success" }),
  };
```

This is my first time setting up both a lambda function, authorisation provider and API Gateway so I might be missing something obvious. I have also tried added `mode: no-cors` to my fetch POST requests however they still fail in a very similar way.

From what I can tell by looking at the logs of the authorizer and the lambda function that uploads the images, is that they are not even being called. So it appears the CORS error is with the API Gateway.

I have seen in a few tutorials that in their aws template yaml files they add an option `AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight` as `False`. I can't see this anywhere in the API Gateway console.

---

**Update**: I have tested my function with the custom authoriser turned off and it works. So I know that CORS works for the options method, and for the returned request on the lambda function. It is the custom authoriser that is the problem.

The flow is currently:

1. Method Request - Auth: [my-auth-0-authorizer](https://github.com/auth0-samples/jwt-rsa-aws-custom-authorizer)
2. Integration Request - Type: Lambda_proxy
3. Lambda function
4. Integration response - [greyed out *Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses*]
5. Method Response: HTTP Status: Proxy (with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response headers)

What do I have to do differently or change to allow my authoriser to respect the CORS config?

---

**Update**: After leaving my API Gateway for a day, successful responses are now working (using the flow mentioned above). I am not sure if there was a glitch in the system or there was unexpected occurring but it is now working. I am still getting a CORS issue but now only with bad responses.

The custom authoriser fails by `return context.fail("Unauthorized");` and when this occurs my browser gets a CORS error. Do I have to set up special gateway responses for 4XX responses?